# Не запускается приложение в android studio

Tags: android-studio

Вчера скачал android studio, уже сделал свой первый проект. Но сегодня при открытии приложения столкнулся с проблемой:

`Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction`

Начал искать в интернете. Находил идею поменять файлик gradle.properties и указать туда

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m`

Не помогло. Далее я удалил Android studio и установил заново. В результате при запуске на моем телефоне (по USB подключил) возникает все та же ошибка, но запустить на виртуалке встроенной в android studio нельзя
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]